# superposition of wavelengths of white light

Tags: waves

Why would different wavelengths of white light does not undergo super position to form a single wave length? Why would different wavelengths travel in vacuum  distinctly?

Comment: White light comes from black body sources and therefore is thermal. What kind of superposition does a thermal source light have over time?

Comment: Light is made of billions of individual photons. The closest they come to mixing is depositing their energy at the same spot at the same time. Like in your eye.

Comment: but in interferance light they can super impose........... isnt it??then why in certain circumstances they cannot supperimpose???